# Ideal placement of "initial" async action in React/Redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I've worked on several React/Redux projects and often have components which need to be initialized in some way with data that comes off-server, so via some kind of async call. Apologies for the open-ended question, but what is the ideal triggering point for such a function? I sometimes use componentDidMount and fire off a Redux action there to populate initial data store (action will fire off a redux-thunk async call, etc) but are there better approaches?

Answer (score 0):

componentDidMount is generally the recommendation for such cases.

componentWillMount is your other option. In a lot of cases, they would basically behave the same, but there are a couple of reasons DidMount is preferred

- Just semantically, using WillMount can be a little confusing. It can give the impression that the async request will resolve prior to render occurring, but that is not the case. Since the request is async, it will resolve whenever it does, componentWillMount will return after initiating the request, and rendering will occur. Using DidMount makes the ordering a bit clearer.
- If server-side rendering, componentWillMount will get called twice, once on the server and then once again on the client. componentDidMount does not get called on the server.
- For a long while, there's been some discussion about possibly deprecating componentWillMount.